# Ruby Frequently United List

Tags: ruby

I got a list `[1, 1, 20, 20, 20, 4, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7]`.

In Ruby, How do I check if the list is "frequently united"?

An example: `[2, 2, 150, 150, 150, 70, 70, 70]` is *frequently united*.

*Edit*

Another example: `[2, 2, 150, 150, 150, 70, 70, 70, 150]` is not *frequently united* because the 150 are not together.

Comment: What does _frequently united_ mean?

Comment: "In Ruby, How do I check if the list is "frequently united"?" – You do it by specifying what "frequently united" means and then write a program which checks for that property. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 2):

Something like checking if the next element is equal to the current one?, like:

```
p [1, 1, 20, 20, 20, 4, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7].chunk_while(&:==).all? { |e| e.size > 1 }
p [2, 2, 150, 150, 150, 70, 70, 70].chunk_while(&:==).all? { |e| e.size > 1 }
# => false
# => true
```

Edit:

```
def some_method(array)
  hash = Hash.new(0)
  array.each { |e| hash[e] += 1 } 

  if hash.values.any?(&1.method(:==)) 
    true
  else 
    array.chunk_while(&:==).all? { |e| e.size > 1 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir ! it works !

Comment: If you have a single element, it will return `false`, for example: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3].chunk_while(&:==).all? { |e| e.size > 1 }` returns `false`. Is it a problem?

Comment: you're right. that could be a problem. how do you make sure it returns true if the list contains a single element ?

Comment: What about creating a hash with each value in the array as the hash key and its frequency in it as the key value, then you can check if any value in the resulting hash is equal to 1, as said André, then return true, otherwise the next step.